# Want to ROUND the Data according to DAY difference

Tags: oracle

Query :

```
  select 
      TO_CHAR((to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY'),     
      TO_CHAR(to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level,'DD-MM-YYYY') ,        
      to_number(regexp_substr(IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION, '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE(IP_END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(IP_START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || regexp_substr(IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION, '[A-Z]') as IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION
         FROM
        dual
        CONNECT BY
        level <= to_date(IP_END_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date(IP_START_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1;
```

-> Data in Query :

```
  select 
      TO_CHAR((to_date('16-07-2018 11:02','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+ (level-1)),'DD-MM-YYYY'),     
      TO_CHAR(to_date('16-07-2018 11:02','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + level,'DD-MM-YYYY'),      
      to_number(regexp_substr('4000 T', '^\d+'))/(TO_DATE('18-07-2018 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE('16-07-2018 11:02', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) || regexp_substr('4000 T', '[A-Z]') as IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION 
      FROM
      dual
      CONNECT BY
      level <= to_date('18-07-2018 00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('16-07-2018 11:02','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1;
```

Output will Be :
[image]

But its should be **2000 T**
Not : If Start Date: 16-07-2018 00:00 & End Date : 19-07-2018 00:00 then Day Difference is 3 Days & Consumption is 4000 T then Inserted Consumption Should be 1333.333333333333 T ~ 1334 T in each date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing dates, you should store them in your table as the `DATE` data type (and not as strings).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd6735/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table( id, ip_start_date, ip_end_date, ip_plan_consumption ) AS
  SELECT 1,
         DATE '2018-07-16' + INTERVAL '11:02' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         DATE '2018-07-18' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         '4000 T'
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,
         DATE '2018-07-16' + INTERVAL '11:02' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         DATE '2018-07-16' + INTERVAL '23:08' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         '3000 T'
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,
         DATE '2018-07-10' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         DATE '2018-07-13' + INTERVAL '23:59' HOUR TO MINUTE,
         '15000 U'
  FROM   DUAL
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( id, start_dt, end_dt, consumption, units ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         TRUNC( IP_START_DATE ),
         GREATEST( TRUNC( IP_START_DATE ) + 1, TRUNC( IP_END_DATE ) ),
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION, '^\d+' ) ),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION, '\S+$' )
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT id,
       t.column_value     AS start_dt, 
       t.column_value + 1 AS end_dt,      
       consumption / ( end_dt - start_dt ) || units AS IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION 
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT d.start_dt + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY d.start_dt + LEVEL - 1 < d.end_dt
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       ) t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd6735/1/0)**:

```
| ID |             START_DT |               END_DT | IP_PLAN_CONSUMPTION |
|----|----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|
|  1 | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-17T00:00:00Z |               2000T |
|  1 | 2018-07-17T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-18T00:00:00Z |               2000T |
|  2 | 2018-07-16T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-17T00:00:00Z |               3000T |
|  3 | 2018-07-10T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-11T00:00:00Z |               5000U |
|  3 | 2018-07-11T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-12T00:00:00Z |               5000U |
|  3 | 2018-07-12T00:00:00Z | 2018-07-13T00:00:00Z |               5000U |
```

Comment: i need to store as string because of some other technical Reasons.

Comment: @AnjiTandel "I need to store data in the wrong data type for technical reasons" is the wrong thing to do. You may be forced to do it for "business" reasons but should never do it for "technical" reasons as there are many better "technical" reasons to use the correct tool (data type) for the job. Beyond that, the answer still applies - just convert it from a string to a date in the sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause and if you need to convert it back to a string then you can use `TO_CHAR` in the output `SELECT` clause.

Comment: my whole store procedure is updated Above code, because i add your code in that, its showing error.  @MT0